# Разрабатываю игру на JS. Как хранить таблицу рекордов?

Tags: javascript, html, разработка-игр, cookie

Я новичок, как Вы понимаете. Разрабатываю игру для курсовой работы. Делаю её на чистом JavaScript. Игра полностью готова кроме сохранения статистики. Игра по сути очень проста - игра в кости. В требованиях к курсовой есть пункт, который звучит так : "Предусмотреть  сохранение  статистики результатов игроков.".
Вот собственно и вопрос: как это лучше сделать?
Надо принять во внимание тот факт, что на данный момент игра существует в виде папки с файлами и запускается в браузере путём открытия HTML файла.
Рассматривал сохранение статистики в локальный файл или же сохранение при помощь "Cookie". Пока особо не разбирался в этих способах и что бы не тратить время зря решил задать этот вопрос и узнать у более опытных людей, как лучше организовать сохранение статистики.
Есть две переменные, одна с именем игрока, другая с количеством очков. Нужно, что бы статистика записывалась при нажатии кнопки (кнопка уже готова, осталось только написать внутрь код) и что бы потом я мог отобразить таблицу игроков и их результатов (желательно с возможностью сортировки по количеству очков).

Comment: Требование сохранения неопределённое. Хранить можно в (1) localStorage, куках, скачивать файл и загружать его в страницу обратно руками, копипастить json руками, (2) сохранять на диск через серверный код например на node.js или php. Если сохранение означает "только на время пока открыта вкладка", то варианты (1) подойдут, иначе придётся писать серверную часть (2).

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Так мой вопрос и состоит в том, что я не могу определиться как хранить данные. И что бы не тратить время на поиски и тестирование различных способов - я обратился сюда. Что может посоветовать более опытный программист? Мне нужен максимально простой способ. Ещё раз опишу условия: игра существует в виде локальных файлов, так и будет запускаться, напрямую, открытием HTML с помощью браузера. Есть две переменные в коде JS (имя и очки), нужно записывать эти данные каждый раз при завершении игры и что бы была потом возможность отобразить.
Итак вопрос: каким способом лучше и проще это сделать?

Answer (score 2):

Лучше выучить SQL. При желании за двое суток освоишь.
Самый простой способ хранить в localStorage. Но выйдет какая-то ерунда скорее всего. Ниже написал пример как установить значения в localStorage и как их достать. По умолчанию установи 2 рандомных имени и очки по 0.
И каждым нажатием на кнопку делай новые setItem, для перезаписи. Будут вопросы пиши, вместе разберемся. Учти что больше 2 имен ты в доске лидеров не выведешь, обязательно нужна база данных, желательно на SQL

```
localStorage.setItem('user1', JSON.stringify([name1, point1]));

localStorage.setItem('user2', JSON.stringify([name2, point2]));

const user1 = localStorage.getItem('user1');

const user2 = localStorage.getItem('user2');
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ, я уже не надеялся, что кто либо ответит и даже перестал заходить на сайт, что бы проверить. Ещё пока не разобрался в вашем коде, но уже есть такие мысли: Если мы можем хранить строку, то почему бы не записывать данные в одну строку, а потом уже написать код, который будет это всё отображать и сортировать так как мне надо. Я ранее писал похожий алгоритм, который преобразовывал строку с элементы массива (в строке они были отделены пробелами), а затем чётные элементы будут имена, нечётные счёт, а там уже надо будет думать как это отображать.

Comment: Ключевой вопрос: я всё таки могу хранить строку? Насколько большую?

Comment: Я думаю бесконечно большую. Я могу показать тебе как базу создать. Напиши мне на почту gabidov05@gmail.com

Comment: Всё не было времени написать, я уже давно сделал сохранение статистики через сохранение строки в localStorage. При этом статистика сортируется по возрастанию очков. Ещё раз спасибо за пример с использованием localStorage.